# how to drop duplicates based on specific column in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table called "Mytable" as below(just an example), it has two columns Hash and last_checked.

```
Hash    last_checked
1       2021-04-01T12:14:00+00:00
1       2021-04-02T12:14:00+00:00
1       2021-04-03T12:14:00+00:00
2       2021-04-01T12:14:00+00:00
2       2021-04-02T12:14:00+00:00
2       2021-04-03T12:14:00+00:00
```

I want to delete duplicate hash values based on the last_checked column/field. I need to retain latest last_checked date values. output table as below

```
Hash    last_checked
1       2021-04-03T12:14:00+00:00
2       2021-04-03T12:14:00+00:00
```

I didnot find answer anywhere, so hoping I may get answer here.Thank you

Comment: It has only 2 columns, if so how would you know which to delete. You can alternatively use row_num function and using rank, or using distinct, you can identify the latest record, but to perform delete operation, you need to identify the unique rows in a table and just having these 2  fields, there is no way a delete can be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have HASHTABLE  AS TABLE With Columns Hash & last_checked

Using Subquery from this HASHTABLE  after USING Predicate , Also Used Qualify Predicate to filter on Windows Functions.

```
DELETE FROM  HASHTABLE   USING 
(

 SELECT HASHVAL,last_checked FROM HASHTABLE Qualify  ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY HASHVAL ORDER BY last_checked  DESC)  !=1   

) AS

HASHTABLE_DERIVED   

WHERE  HASHTABLE.HASHVAL=HASHTABLE_DERIVED.HASHVAL AND HASHTABLE.last_checked=HASHTABLE_DERIVED.last_checked
```